# If a chord of a circle bisects the angle between two other chords, would it pass through the centre?

Tags: solution-verification, contest-math, circles

> In a circle with centre 'O', PA and PB are two chords. PC is the chord that bisects the angle APB. The tangent to the circle at C is drawn meeting PA and PB extended at Q and R respectively. If QC=3, QA=2 and RC=4, then length of RB equals?

I found its solution [here](https://www.toppr.com/ask/question/in-a-circle-with-centre-o-pa-and-pb-are-two-chords-pc-is-the/) but it assumes that the chord PC passes through centre O. Is it implied anywhere in question?

Comment: Yes, if the two "outer" chords are congruent.

Comment: I share you doubts $PC$ does not have to go thru the centre. All you need is to have $AC=BC$ and you can move point $P$ around as you please.

Comment: However the solution that you referenced seems OK to me, it does not require $PC$ to contain $O$

Comment: @Vasili didn't that solution use that the tangent is perpendicular to radius, thereby implying PC is diameter?

Comment: @OscarLanzi ues I agree but I think here the chords need not be same.

Comment: @aarbee: you are right!! However, we can come to the same result using the law of sines: $3:\sin \theta=PQ:\sin \alpha, 4:\sin \theta=PR:\sin (\pi-\alpha) \implies PQ:PR=3:4$

Comment: @Vasili thankyou very much.